# insert name and value pair

Tags: javascript, json, insert

example :

`var data = { name : "John",age : 19}`

I want to add another pair inside the json object.

`{gender : male}`

so that it will become

`data = { name : "John",age : 19,gender : "male" }`

Comment: <pedantic>It isn't really a "JSON object" you have here, but a JavaScript one</pedantic>.  JSON is a text format, and BTW the key names must be double quoted.

Comment: @RayToal: Not "pedantic" at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is

```
data.gender = "male";
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, either:

```
data.gender = "male";
```

or

```
data['gender'] = "male";
```

(These are equivalent.)

If you are using jQuery (or one of many other libraries), you may have an "extend" function that is useful for that. It "merges" two Javascript objects. In jQuery:

```
$.extend(data, { gender: "male" });
```

This is nice because you can extend the JSON object with more than one value.

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = { name : "John",age : 19};
var update = {gender : "male"};


function merge(target, source){
    for(var prop in source){
        target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
    return target;
}

var merged = merge(data, update);
```

This will add all properties in `update` to `data`. Using the returned value is optional. `data` itself gets updated inside the function as it is object.

Or if you use jQuery

```
var merged = $.extend(data, update);
```

Using jQuery we can do a deep level merging

```
var update = {gender : "male", address:{house:"house1", street:"street1", pin:"pin1"}};
var merged = $.extend(true, data, update);
```

To achieve the same using plain javascript you have to modify  and recursively call the function I have written above .

Comment: Jaider wanted to add: Or without modifying the data: `var merged = $.extend({}, data, update);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = { name : "John",age : 19};
data.gender = "male";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.gender = "male"
```

More information here : [Dynamically Add Variable Name Value Pairs to JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071499/dynamically-add-variable-name-value-pairs-to-json-object)