# Using ajax in Orchard CMS

Tags: jquery, ajax, content-management-system, orchardcms

I want to pass Json data to Controller by Ajax (I had refered to [AntiForgery and JSON incompatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504090/antiforgery-and-json-incompatible) before) and this is my code:

Ajax:

```
var self = this;
self.Url = ko.observable();
self.Description = ko.observable();
self.ValueName = ko.observable();
self.MatchRegex = ko.observable();
self.__RequestVerificationToken = ko.observable('@Html.AntiForgeryTokenValueOrchard()');

self.Xpaths = ko.observableArray([
    { Name: 'RootXPath', Xpath: '', Regex: '', isRootXPath: true }
]);

self.addRow = function () {
    self.Xpaths.push({ Name: '', Xpath: '', Regex: '', isRootXPath: false });
};

self.removeRow = function () {
    if (this.name == 'RootXPath')
        return;
    self.Xpaths.remove(this);
};
self.executeExtractScript = function () {
var myValues = JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self));
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EExtractScriptTemp", "Home", new { area = "Crawler" })',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myValues,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function () {
        $(".result").html("Success");
        runEffect();
    },
    error: function () {
        $(".result").html("Error");
        runEffect();
    }
});
```

};

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EExtractScriptTemp(ExtractScriptTempModels objectJSon) {
   return null;
}
```

And the real value of **myValues** is (by inspecting element in Chrome):

```
"{"__RequestVerificationToken":"6ygUGMe1PER7FizLBqCDJLcSfp9zuA4dcRyUHCwVwkWzOTO0AiRF8QRSDwoqRI-SD9FfiFvF-jozFKL10HS21xTBlRP4EndYbmGhPSX_Kuk1F0r0swYnGZZxZdy793eQxfmkvjIUtnwdLtrg0q8zhFdZNJBvmiPA6dC57prmw1c1","Xpaths":[{"Name":"RootXPath","Xpath":"","Regex":"","isRootXPath":true}]}"
```

However, it still rose error

> {"The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\"
>   is not present."}

I have tried to use both @Matthew's method and @Giscard Biamby's but it was work no longer.

What's my problem ?
Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

Don't stringify your payload. Let jQuery take care of sending the data. There are examples in the existing code. Search for `$.post(` in the Orchard code. You'll find one in Orchard.MediaPicker.

Comment: I will try to solve it according to your advice and reply result later. Thanks @Bertrand Le Roy

Answer (score 0):

try to add  `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to head of the function

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult EExtractScriptTemp(ExtractScriptTempModels objectJSon) {
   return null;
}
```

in client i send data like this

```
//find the Token
 var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

     data: {
    "someText": "Text",
      "__RequestVerificationToken": token
        },
```

After this changes error is gone (in my case)