# posting data with Axios

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I need to use a code like this:

```
vr1 = 'firstName'
value1 = 'Fred'
vr2 = 'lastName'
value2 = 'Flinstone'

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
     vr1: Value1,
     vr2: Value2
  }
});
```

so, it will be the same as executing:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

Is this possible using Java Script 6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create your own object and pass it to your data request like this:

```
var obj = {
  [myKey]: value,
}

or 

var obj = {};
obj['name'] = value;
obj['anotherName'] = anotherValue;
```

[Creating object with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys)

[Dynamically Add Variable Name Value Pairs to JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071499/dynamically-add-variable-name-value-pairs-to-json-object)

edited: how to post request

```
const profile = {};
//...fill your object like this for example
profile[key] = value;

axios.post('profile/student', profile)
  .then(res => {
    return res;
  });
```

Comment: but, how with Axios I could send that object? The docs say nothing about that. At the end the sent data must become JSON for the server to understand

Comment: i don't understand where's the problem. I added one more example. I hope that can be useful for you

Comment: The problem is that the posted tutorials use, instead of an object variable as you did, they used {... }  to represent the object and some times it confuses me with programming blocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Try this one also and replace

```
baseURL
```

with your own hostname url

```
import axios from 'axios'

let var1 = 'firstName'
let value1 = 'Fred'
let var2 = 'lastName'
let value2 = 'Flinstone'

const api = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://example.com'})
api.post('/user/12345', {
    var1: value1,
    var2: value2
})
.then(res => {
     console.log(res)
})
.catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this it works for me

```js
const obj = {
  firstName: Fred,
  lastName: Flinstone
}
axios
  .post(
    "url",
    this.obj,
  )
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the keys dynamic, surround them in brackets `[]`

```
vr1 = 'firstName'
value1 = 'Fred'
vr2 = 'lastName'
value2 = 'Flinstone'

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
     [vr1]: Value1,
     [vr2]: Value2
  }
});
```