# Dynamically Add Variables as Value Pairs to Array

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically store pairs of values in a object. I have a code similar to:

```
obj = {};

avariable = "Name x";
anothervariable = 100;
var name = avariable;
var value = anothervariable;

obj[name] = value;
```

It does not work, the console.log shows: obj = [object Object]

I tried to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071499/dynamically-add-variable-name-value-pairs-to-json-object) with a very similar problem, but I do not know in advance the "name" so I cannot use:

```
obj['name y']
```

My final goes is to store a value for each name and to restore those values later on with a loop given the name.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `console.dir(obj)` yield?

Comment: `obj[name] = value` should work. You've probably just not logged it correctly to see it there.

Comment: I think the question is misleading. array has no key value pair, it goes with an index. I think your refers to creating an key value pair object using bracket notation.

Comment: `console.log(obj)` and `console.dir(obj)` and working fine for me.

Comment: You also should avoid bad practice in using `var name` in the Window scope as it will attempt to override the preexisting [`Window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) in browser environments.

Comment: Like @CodyPace, I too cannot reproduce in [my Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/PlushEsteemedLifecycle#script.js).

Comment: is what you tried is to alert obj? Thats the only way it shows [Object Object]

Comment: whatever the case you most likely need to convert the object to a string to keep from seeing [object Object]. `alert(JSON.stringify(obj))` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: Thank you all! I was logging other variables and that is why it was not showing correctly, but both console.dir(obj) and console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) show that the values are added correctly to obj.

Comment: You should put more effort into _properly_ describing your problems. _“It does not work, the console.log shows […]”_ - that part, _how_ you are actually logging the values, was the most relevant here, but specifically _that_ you failed to show us.

Comment: I did not know it was relevant, my code was different in other parts too. All the answers above made me understand the issue, so they were helpful even if I did not include the most relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, I summarized below:

The Code above is correct. I was concatenating multiple variables and that is why I was getting [object Object].

```
console.log("callback called, flag: "+ flagq+", obj = "+obj);
```

console.log(obj), console.dir(obj) and console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) show that the values are added correctly to obj.

Comment: It was not actually because you logged multiple values - that works fine without any problem - but because you _concatenated_ multiple values into a single string.